# Connection to Amazon S3 is not establishing

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

i am trying to upload an image on amazon s3 from by android app, i provides the exact bucket name but i am not sure about cognito pool id . the account is not my own i am using my Sir's account he provided me these 3 things

pool id ap-northeast-1_IsLv8eL4V
pool ARN arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-northeast-1:398391276840:
userpool/ap-northeast-1_IsLv8eL4V

i have try all but still i am facing this error

y E/UploadTask: Failed to upload: 3 due to IdentityPool 'ap-northeast-1:398391276840' not found. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: dbf79e2e-7d81-11e6-86c1-636bec177bb9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the exception because you are using User Pool Id as Identity Pool Id. For more information on integration Cognito User Pool with Cognito Identity Pool, refer to these documentations

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html

https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxNYVQQ3A2LT6Y/Using-Android-SDK-with-Amazon-Cognito-Your-User-Pools